# How to make limited items as Bold in Listbox for Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to make Some items of my listbox as bold (based on some database flag) in Silverlight application.
Eg :- 
Item1
Item2
**Item3**
Item4
**Item5**

I've looked on net and found some solution for windows application but nothing for web.

Answer (score 0):

Use converters for this purpose. Apply and Pass relevant parameter values. If you post your XAML/C# I can Correct it.

I do not want to write from scratch.